# import all future features

Tags: python, import

Just curious, I tried `from __future__ import *`, but I received this error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: future feature * is not defined
```

Well, that makes sense.  A `__future__` import is a little special and doesn't follow the normal rules, but it got me to thinking: how *can* I import all the future features?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't, and that's by design. This is because more `__future__` features might be added in the future, and those can break your code.

Imagine that in 2.x, the only `__future__` feature was `division`. Then in 2.y, a new `__future__` feature, `print_function`, is introduced. All of a sudden my code has broken:

```
from __future__ import *
print "Hello, World!"
```

You *can*, however, import `__future__`, and inspect its contents:

```
>>> import __future__
>>> [x for x in dir(__future__) if x.islower() and x[0] != '_']
['absolute_import', 'all_feature_names', 'division', 'generator_stop', 'generators', 'nested_scopes', 'print_function', 'unicode_literals', 'with_statement']
```

Note that these are not features and you should not try to import them. They instead describe which features are available, and from which versions they are.

Answer (score 1):

The current maximal import would be:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
```

If I had to guess, that will be good until the end of the Python 2.7 series in 2020. There's no harm in including the old ones, like `generators`, but it's a no-op once the feature is standard.

Answer (score 0):

You actually *can* import every feature from `__future__` (with a small workaround).
The following code lines are all one-liners and highly compressed.

Python >= 3.6:

```
[exec(f"from __future__ import {x}") for x in dir(__import__("__future__")) if x.islower() and not x.startswith("all_") and x[0] != '_']
```

Python < 3.6:

```
[exec(f"from __future__ import "+x) for x in dir(__import__("__future__")) if x.islower() and not x.startswith("all_") and x[0] != '_']
```

Note:
You don't have to assign the resulting list to a variable because it contains only `None`s.

A simple text version of these snippets:
Import everything of a list of everything in `__future__` that contains only lower case letters, does not start with `all_` and whose first letter is not `_`.